# Using FakeItEasy to have a faked method call raise an event?

Tags: c#, mocking, fakeiteasy

I'm trying to do something along the lines of:

```
A.CallTo(() => fakeTimer.Start()).Invokes(() => 
    fakeTimer.Elapsed += Raise.With<ElapsedEventArgs>(ElapsedEventArgs.Empty).Now);
```

The `fakeTimer` is a fake of `ITimer`, a wrapper interface per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9088455/8205).

<strike>Obviously this doesn't work, since I cannot do an assignment inside an Experssion Tree.</strike>

What I am actually tying to achieve is simulating raising timer events when the `Start` method was called. This way I can assert that a call to `Start` indeed happened.

Any (alternative) ideas?

**Edit** I'm an idiot and the fault is my own! I accidentally added an extra `A.CallTo`, where I shouldn't have. Instead of deleting this question, I'll keep it to award [Patrik Hägne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46187/patrik-hagne) his rightful reputation :)

Comment: Try wrapping the expression with braces: `A.CallTo(() => { ... })`.

Comment: @mellamokb it doesn't work, because a Lambda expression with a statement body (`{...}`) cannot be converted to an Expression Tree...

Comment: Ah, it takes a `Expression<Action>` ([source link](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/blob/master/Source/FakeItEasy/A.cs)).  You might have to explicitly cast it then, since `Action` and `Expression<Action>` are technically ambiguous: `(Expression<Action>)(() => ... )`.

Comment: I think you should've left the question in its original state to help googlers. I googled "fake it easy event was raised" and got here, and was confused because the same code snippet is in the answer and question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, is this it???

```
A.CallTo(() => fakeTimer.Start()).Invokes(() => 
    fakeTimer.Elapsed += Raise.With<ElapsedEventArgs>(ElapsedEventArgs.Empty).Now);
```